# What's the opposite of "speaking clearly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

When somebody talks in a way where they swallow parts of a word, talk very fast or talk in a way that is difficult for most listeners to comprehend, what do you call the way this person speaks? I'm looking for an adverb that conveys the meaning "unclearly", "mangled" or just "ununderstandbly" (yeah I know it's not a word).

Comment: What is wrong with "speaking unclearly"?

Comment: Note: "talks in a way where they swallow parts of a word, talk very fast or talk in a way that is difficult for most listeners to comprehend".  All three things are totally different.  Which do you want to know about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone is speaking [unintelligibly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unintelligible): being such that understanding or comprehension is difficult or impossible; incomprehensible.

Whether because of [mumbling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mumble) (to speak words indistinctly, as by lowering the voice or partially closing the mouth.), 
[muttering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/muttered) (to speak indistinctly in low tones), [garbling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garble) (to mix up or distort to such an extent as to make misleading or incomprehensible) or [incoherence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garble) (expressed in an incomprehensible or confusing way; unclear), it is unclear.

A good thesaurus and these words should get you started on the exact word you want.

Comment: Very clearly put.

Answer (score 0):

[To garble one's words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garble): is a useful expression that  can be used to convey the idea of talking fast distorting words so that they are difficult to understand.

> - To mix up or distort to such an extent as to make misleading or incomprehensible